# NFS filesystem 100% full - 'No space left on device' error, cannot remove or truncate files

Tags: ubuntu, files, filesystems, nfs

I'm getting a `No space left on device` error when I try to remove or truncate a file on a Ubuntu server. This seems to be because the NFS filesystem is 100% full and all inodes are used.

Running `df -T` gives the following result:

```
Filesystem                   Type        1K-blocks         Used    Available Use% Mounted on
...
rc-stor6-ib:/centers/cfce    nfs      228910395392 228910395392            0 100% /mnt/cfce-stor1
...
```

and `df -i` gives:

```
Filesystem                          Inodes    IUsed         IFree IUse% Mounted on
...
rc-stor6-ib:/centers/cfce         27410037 27410037             0  100% /mnt/cfce-stor1
...
```

I don't have admin privileges, and so far I've tried multiple methods to manually remove some files to free up space. However, `rm -f`, `mv * /tmp`, `truncate -s 0` and piping from `/dev/null` have all returned the `No space left on device` error, for example:

```
(base) rh476@CFCE2:~/WGCNA/project_wgcna$ rm -f brg_TOM_allsamples-block.1.RData 
rm: cannot remove 'brg_TOM_allsamples-block.1.RData': No space left on device
```

Is there anything else I can do to free up space and fix the issue?

Comment: Can you log into the server and try those things on the machine?

Comment: Yes, I've sshed into the server and run the commands I mentioned but I'm only getting ```no space left on device```

Comment: If you are not the system administrator of the NFS server, then I would suggest that you contact the admin to get them to figure out what's using all the space and take appropriate action.  It's their job, not yours.

Comment: What commands did you run exactly? `rm -f` _what_? `mv * /tmp` wouldn't help unless `/tmp` is another partition. `truncate -s 0`, like `rm -f` would need arguments. Can you please [edit] your question and show an actual command you ran and the exact error? You shouldn't be getting `no space left` errors with `rm` for example.

Comment: @terdon I've edited with an example. In my case ```/tmp``` is mounted on another partition, which was why I tried ```mv * /tmp```.

Comment: Are you the only one mounting that nfs share? Then I'd suggest to unmount it and try again to `rm` in an `ssh` session on the remote machine.

Comment: It's rather unlikely to run out of both disk space and inodes simultaneously. Perhaps the NFS server is a NAS device of some sort, and is trying to signal some sort of error condition by reporting that it is full. If the NFS server includes a snapshotting mechanism that tracks all changes to the share, that might explain why you cannot even delete any files. **Contact the administrator of the NFS server.**